# How to compute centered moving average in an array:MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, signal-processing

I have an 40x2 matrix, in which the first column shows day index and the 2nd column value for each day:

```
1   11
2   12
3   10
4   10
5   12
6   11
7   12
8   10
9   12
10  10
11  12
12  12
13  10
14  9
15  12
16  12
17  12
18  11
19  10
20  10
21  11
22  11
23  10
24  8
25  9
26  9
27  9
28  8
29  8
30  12
31  11
32  9
33  9
34  12
35  11
36  11
37  10
38  10
39  11
40  9
```

How to compute centered moving average with 30 days moving window taking 15th of the day as the midpoint and traversing backward 14 days and forward 15 days? Basically I want to compute:

```
Xavg = median[X(i-14):X(i+15)].
```

Where `X(i)` is the data point. I found a few thread using convolution operator but could not find out how to fix step size since my midpoint is located on the 15th day and further how to compute median effect?

Comment: median is not a moving average. For average, you can use `conv`. For median, @Dominic's answer is fine

Comment: or, you can use `movmedian` (or is it `movmean`? i'm confused now)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in a vectorised way with `arrayfun`.

```matlab
window_size = 15;

Xavg = arrayfun( @(i) median(X(i-window_size+1:i+window_size,2)), window_size:size(X,1)-window_size)
```

Which simply applies the median function over a window `i-14:i+15` for i in the range `15:25` (where the full window will fit).

Comment: What is `X` here?

Comment: X is the 40x20 input matrix - I took the notation from the question.